# Close range shadow rendering

Tags: rendering, eevee-render-engine, shadows

When I render using Cycles, I get the shadows I am expecting:
[image: Render view with Cycles]

When I render using Eeevee, Some are missing:
[image: Render view with Eeevee]

I have tried the suggestions [in this post (turning on Contact Shadows)](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/192015/shadows-of-small-objects-in-eevee), however the shadows then become 3d and render incorrectly:
[image]

Does anyone know of any workarounds to this? I am working at small scale, i.e. the height of the 2 yellow plates are 40mm/50mm.

[This is the example blender file I created for this post](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1xrT7nVd56ABVHREMqBYGY0GrDJ3qqZGh/view?usp=sharing), which should demo the problem upon clicking on the Rendered Viewport Shading button.

Thanks for any assistance!

Comment: Yeah, that's strange. I downloaded the file. The objects (at least the "sheet") don't cast a shadow below a Z height of 49mm (29 for the "gear") - even if I delete the old light, add a new one and move it closer (the light not the sheet). For some reason, it's the Z-height of the objects that's causing it - not the light position, nor the proximity to the light.

Comment: Should I report this as a bug?

Comment: I'm not sure. I built your setup from the ground up on my end, and was able to recreate it to some extent. I was still able to bring the shadow back by moving the light, but no other settings seem to affect it. It might be a bug, or simply a limitation of how EEVEE handles shadows. I don't really know enough about it to determine either way.